# Why system call read() does not work when using user input

Tags: c, linux, unix, system-calls

It`s a file copying program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int fd1,fd2, ndata;
    char data[128];
    char *openname[1], *creatname[1]; 

    write(1, "Write open file name\n", 24); //user input

    read(0, openname, 30 );

    write(1, "Write creat file name\n", 25); //user input

    read(0, creatname,30);

    if((fd1 = open(openname, 0666))<0)
        {
            perror("cannot open the file");
            exit(1);
        }

    if((fd2 = creat(creatname,0666))<0)
        {
            perror("cannot create the file");
            exit(1);
        }

    while((ndata = read(fd1, data, 128))>0)
        {
            if((write(fd2, data, ndata))!=ndata)
                {
                    perror("cannot write the file");
                    exit(1); 
                } 
        }

    close(fd1);
    close(fd2); 

    write(1, "File copy is done.",19);

    return 0;

}
```

This code ain`t work. This code print the error message:

```
cannot open the file.
```

but if i change the code to this :

```
if((fd1 = open("copy.c", 0666))<0)
```

and this :

```
if((fd2 = creat("real.c",0666))<0)
```

worked well.

Why this error happend? Please answer.

Comment: `perror` would follow `cannot open the file` with a message explaining the  `errno`. What is it for you?

Comment: sorry. that is the ENOENT  : No such file or directory (POSIX.1)

Comment: you are using variable `openname` and `creatname` wrong. check by implementing break point that what you are getting in these variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declarations of `openname` and `creatname` are incorrect. They should be:

```
char openname[31], creatname[31];
```

`read()` does not add a null terminator to the input, you need to add it. `read()` returns the number of bytes read. So it should be:

```
int nread = read(0, openname, sizeof openname -1);
openname[nread-1] = '\0'; // subtract 1 to overwrite the newline
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of `openname` and `creatname` is wrong, and `gcc -Wall -g` would have warned you. Declare e.g. `char openname[256];`

And you should use `fgets(openname, sizeof(openname), stdin);` to read it.

If you insist on using `read`, take care of the newline (if any) and add a zero terminating byte.

Learn also to use the `gdb` debugger.

Answer (score 1):

`read` is very low level. In this case, it reads 30 bytes, *including* your enter key and also without a terminating null-byte. So the filename won't be what you think you've entered, it will contain additional garbage (and could even make your program crash due to the missing null-termination). You want to use [`fgets` or `readline` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, by using `read()` to input the file names, you are making this unnecessarily hard for yourself: it does not terminate the input with NUL, is not guaranteed to read the number of characters you expect, etc.

My advice would be to stick with `scanf()` or `fgets()`.